# IE9 JavaScript OOP Function call doesnt work

Tags: javascript, oop, internet-explorer-9

in IE9 a JavaScript OOP Function call doesnt work.

here my Code:

```
var newobj = new SAObject();

<input onclick="newobj.function()" />
```

if i click this button, nothing happens. No Alert, nothing. But in Firefox everything is fine.

Someone had the same Problem and can help me?

EDIT:

onchange at a SelectBox does not work, too.

```
$("#SelectBox").change(function() { ...

 <select id="SelectBox">...
```

Comment: For the 2nd problem, we need to see more code.

Comment: Can you show us the complete actual code

Answer (score 2):

```
<input onclick="newobj.function()" />
```

`function` is a [reserved word](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_7.htm#Section_7.6.1.1) in JavaScript. Don't use it as an identifier name.

Comment: I don't have access to IE9 right now, but you can set properties like `{"on" : new Date()}` just fine. If JS Objects couldn't have Javascript keywords as keys, it'd break JSON.

Comment: @Robert: yes, but you'll have to put quotes around them and access them using the square bracket notation, like `foo["on"] = …`.

Comment: That's not true either as this works in Chrome/Firefox and IE http://jsfiddle.net/robert/zAeWn/ I'll agree with you that it should be avoided if possible, but I don't think it's the answer to his question.

Comment: @Robert: oh wait, `on` is not a reserved word; try `in` instead.

Comment: Alright, I can get that to break in IE, so I stand corrected. Now we just need to find out if he's using .function() in the jQuery method as well.